# How can I get a contact's version or modified time?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to figure out if there is a property in Android contacts that states if a contact has been modified.

I read that it was possible to read a contact's version via the field ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.VERSION, but I wasn't able to retrieve its value. I always get an IllegalArgumentException.

Does someone know how to get the contact's version or if there is another way to find out if a contact has been modified since the last scanning of the address book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres the code, I havent tested it, as I was busy with my work.

```
    public void getVersion() {
    //specify which fields of RawContacts table to be retrieved.
    String[] projection = new String[] {RawContacts.VERSION};

    //query the RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
    Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,null,null,null);

  while(cur.moveToNext()){
    String version = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.VERSION));    
    Log.i("VersionRetriever", version);
   }

  //Always remember to close the cursor. Otherwise it leads to side-effects.
  cur.close();
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I edited your code, performing a sum of the RawContacts versions.

Comment: I would really love if you could add your code here so its easy for people to understand and make fewer mistakes(if at all).

Comment: @jaydeepw...I am in search of update time of as contact which forced me to see this post and I got the Version of all accounts. When I try to change any info in any of the contact that version number really does not change so my question is how to get the modification time from VERSION?

Answer (score 0):

try RawContacts.CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP instead of RawContacts.VERSION.

Comment: It doesn't provide modified time of a contact but a status update timestamp which is usually null / not assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a specific data type (like phone or name), was changed you can check Data.DATA_VERSION (but on Data.CONTENT_URI).